# Filter data with API/SQL or with Angular?

Tags: sql, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm having a bit of hard time trying to decide how I should filter results in a small-ish Angular SPA with a couple of thousand hits per month:

Let's say I have a database table `albums`, which contains the download counts of each album in the field `downloads`. I want to show the Top 3 most downloaded albums in the view. Should I just use `$http.get('api/albums')`, which returns all albums in JSON, and then `ng-repeat="album in albums | filter: showTop3"`.

Or is it better to filter them with SQL, for example `$http.get('api/albums?show=top3')`, where the key=value runs code that executes (as a crude example) something like `SELECT * FROM albums ORDER BY downloads DESC LIMIT 3`.

Is there any practical difference between those two in a small site? Speed or maintainability-wise?

Comment: just the code alone should make it obvious. Simple query strings on both ends vs looping through arrays to manually do the calculations just to throw out most of the data

Comment: That's what I thought also. It's just that most Angular example sites, guides, etc. always seem do the first. I guess they are just doing it for demonstration. The only sort-of advantage I can think of is that there are less database queries. But that's probably not an issue until the site is far bigger.